# I can't put my color div horizontally when I put it in inline block what's the problem please?

Tags: html, css

```
.color {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Devops-Issam/pen/oNMGree

I created a color div to call several colors then horizontally so I put it in inline-block but it refuses to go horizontally above my link.
i have tried to find the problem without success i have the impression that the whole left side of telling me color is blocked

Comment: give width: 100% to parent color element.
But I'd use display: flex for such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it, problem was that your container with colors, and colors had the same class name, in your case "color", i gived class .colors to parent element.

**Code:**

```
<article>
        <h2>Converse Chuck Taylor All Star Low Top</h2>
        <img
          src="https://i.imgur.com/ZrTU3VK.jpeg"
          alt="jpeg"
        />
        <p><strong>$65.00</strong></p>
        <p class="free">Free shipping</p>
        <p>
          Ready to dress up or down, these classic canvas Chucks are an everyday
          wardrobe staple.
        </p>
  
        <a
          class="link"
          href="#"
          >More information &rarr;
        </a>
        <div class="colors">
          <div class="color color-black"></div>
          <div class="color color-blue"></div>
          <div class="color color-red"></div>
          <div class="color color-yellow"></div>
          <div class="color color-green"></div>
          <div class="color color-brown"></div>
        </div>
        <h3>Product details</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Lightweigh, durable canvas sneaker</li>
          <li>Lightly padded footbed for added comfort</li>
          <li>Iconic Chuck Taylor ankle patch.</li>
        </ul>
        <button>Add to cart</button>
      </article>





/* GENERAL */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
  
  /*CONTAINER SECTION*/
  article {
    width: 825px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 4px solid black;
  }
  
  /* TITLE */
  h2 {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  h2::before {
    content: "sale";
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -35px;
    top: -25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  /* MAIN */
  img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }
  
  strong {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  
  .free {
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .link:link,
  :visited {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .link:hover,
  :active {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .color {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  
  .color-black {
    background-color: #000;
  }
  .color-blue {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .color-red {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .color-yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .color-green {
    background-color: green;
  }
  .color-brown {
    background-color: brown;
  }
  
  h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  
  li {
    list-style: square;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  /* MAIN BUTTON */
  button {
    background-color: #000;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 4px solid black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  
  button:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `width: auto;` to the parent element (you'll need to use another class, another selector or inline CSS for that) to allow it to become as wide as its contents.